# Looping through json data is not working with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm trying to loop trough a JSON object, but I did not find out yet why it's not working. I only need the title and description in the event array.

The JSON Object looks like this:

```
{
last_item: null,
total_items: "32",
first_item: null,
page_number: "1",
page_size: "10",
page_items: null,
search_time: "0.033",
page_count: "4",
events: {
event: [
{
watching_count: null,
olson_path: "Europe/Zurich",
calendar_count: null,
comment_count: null,
region_abbr: "SO",
postal_code: null,
going_count: null,
all_day: "0",
latitude: "47.35",
groups: null,
url: "http://eventful.com/events/sons-morpheus-/E0-001-093285411-2?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic",
id: "E0-001-093285411-2",
privacy: "1",
city_name: "Olten",
link_count: null,
longitude: "7.91667",
country_name: "Switzerland",
country_abbr: "CHE",
region_name: "Solothurn",
start_time: "2016-08-06 20:00:00",
tz_id: null,
description: " <strong>Age Limit:</strong> All Ages<br><br> Sons of Morpheus<br><br> ",
modified: "2016-05-09 02:54:25",
venue_display: "1",
tz_country: null,
performers: null,
title: "Sons of Morpheus",
venue_address: null,
geocode_type: "City Based GeoCodes",
tz_olson_path: null,
recur_string: null,
calendars: null,
owner: "evdb",
going: null,
country_abbr2: "CH",
image: null,
created: "2016-05-09 02:54:25",
venue_id: "V0-001-002017740-6",
tz_city: null,
stop_time: null,
venue_name: "Schutzi",
venue_url: "http://eventful.com/venues/schutzi-/V0-001-002017740-6?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic"
},
[...]
```

My controller:

```
.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("https://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?c=music&app_key=XXX&date=Future&location=Solothurn").success(function(data) {
        $scope.eventes = data;
    })
})
```

My loop:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="card in eventes">
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title" ng-bind-html="card.events.event[0].title"></span><br><br>
      <div class="icon">

    </div>
```

Comment: Is the above json your data? What are you trying to iterate? The above information is incomplete/not clear

Comment: @nikhil yes, this is the data

Comment: What exactly do you want to iterate? Please add some more data with limited fields

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** try this:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="card in eventes.events.event">
```

This is the proper mapping to your object/json structure.

**Option 2:** 
Or you can change your controller do this:

```
.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?c=music&app_key=XXX&date=Future&location=Solothurn").success(function(data) {
        $scope.eventes = data.events.event;
    })
})
```

And then you should be able to use your original template:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="card in eventes">
```

Side note, you might want to check for nulls using this way as either data or data.events might be null and throw you a js error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="card in eventes.events.event">
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title" ng-bind-html="card.title"></span><br><br>
      <!-- To access description use card.description -->         
      <div class="icon">

    </div>
```